# Convert col plot to pyramid format

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is this type of plot possible with ggplot? I've seen examples such as this one:

http://alburez.me/2018-03-20-Population-pyramids-in-R-for-beginners/

But actually I want something much more simpler like this one:

[image]

Is this possible in ggplot? My first instinct is to create a bar plot/col plot but cannot make the columns centered like the ones in the attached picture above.

Comment: I don't think centering the bars is an appropriate visualisation for your use case. It would just make them difficult to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure could this be achieved via `ggplot2`. One option would be to make use of `geom_rect` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
  name = factor(c("Gen Z", "Millenials", "Gen X")),
  name_y = c(3:1),
  pct = c(.3, .51, .19)
)

midpoint <- max(dat$pct) / 2
ggplot(dat) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = midpoint - pct / 2, xmax = midpoint + pct / 2,
                ymin = name_y - .45, ymax = name_y + .45),
            fill = "steelblue", color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = midpoint, y = name_y, label = scales::percent(pct)), color = "white", fontface = "bold") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(dat$name_y), labels = unique(dat$name)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]